# How to select 1 record from same values in sql?

Tags: sql

I have a `customer` table:

[image]

I have to display customer names to select for sale. Name can be duplicate, and I have to select record with customer name. How can I select that particular record?

I am using the following query:

```
select tot_amt 
from customer  
where cust_name = 'someone'
```

Comment: If names can be duplicate then you will have to select with something else.  Can you select by Phone number?

Comment: @AntG I have to select with names

Comment: Even if there are more than one result, and you display only 1 result is it ok ?

Comment: @ZainArshad I can display only 1 but what if user selected other and I displayed another record ...

Comment: Simple as it is: you can't. This is why when the user selects a name, you must return an id and not the name to your database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although You should use `cust_id` to display a result as each `cust_id` will be unique, but if you want to show only 1 `row` even if there are `rows` more than *1* in you result then you can use this `query`:

```
select top 1 tot_amt from customer where cust_name='someone';
```

Comment: I can display only 1 but what if user selected other and I displayed another record ...

Comment: Please shoe some more code for "another button" then we can help you better

Comment: Dear Down voter, would you please tell me whats wrong in my answer so thatI can correct it ?

Comment: what if user selected record of `someone` whose credit is 500 and the record I displayed has credit amount of 1000

Comment: not this cant happen @RamiFar you are selecting on `name` not on `credit`

Comment: in your query you are selecting on `name` then how can user select on `credit` ?

Comment: selecting on `name` but record has `amount` column, which will use for further process

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191616/discussion-between-zain-arshad-and-rami-far).